# Race conditions in Tensorflow and control_dependencies when computing gradient at updated point?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

I am now facing a bit complicated problem.

Imagine, you have variables **p** and **v**, functions **f(p)** and **G(p)**
You want to do two steps

1. p = G(p)
2. v = f'(p)   *i.e. first update p and then compute gradient in the new updated p and save it into v*

One can run two times sess.run(), but can we do it in one run?
I have a code

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
import numpy as np
shape = [1000,1000]
a = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.01))
b = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.01))
c = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(shape,stddev=0.01))
params = [a,b,c]

fun =  tf.reduce_sum( tf.multiply(  tf.multiply(a,c),b ) )

o = [ tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape)) for i in xrange(3)]
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

grad = tf.gradients(fun,params)
update_a = tf.assign(a, b + c).op
with tf.control_dependencies([update_a]):
  update_b = tf.assign(b, c + a).op

with tf.control_dependencies([update_b]):
  update_c = tf.assign(c, a  + b ).op

with tf.control_dependencies([update_c]):
  df = tf.gradients(fun,params,gate_gradients=True)
  updates = tf.group(  *[ oi.assign(dfi ) for oi, dfi in zip(o,df)]  )

def computeTotalSum(v):
    return [  np.sum(np.abs(j)) for j in sess.run(v)   ]

print computeTotalSum(params)
print computeTotalSum(o)
print computeTotalSum(grad) 

sess.run(updates)

print computeTotalSum(params)
print computeTotalSum(o)
print computeTotalSum(grad)
```

After running it, I get following answer

```
[7229.5298, 7229.4917, 7227.6387]
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[52.223175, 52.195709, 52.314934]
[10073.588, 16026.059, 25751.27]
[619.71185, 52.195709, 234.3277]
[619.71185, 388.07501, 234.3277]
```

however, I would expect the last two rows to be the same!

Comment: Is this a minimum example for demonstration? Could this be demonstrated with only a and b and without c and any gradient computation?

Comment: Yes, this is a minimum example. The gradient computation is essential and also I need a,b,c